# If you snatch, I trade

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

If you snatch, I trade.

If you work with bites, I isolate,

If you work with celestial bodies, part of me protects.

If you work with the land, I divide.

**What am I?**

Give the reasoning for each line!

Since it's been answered already, an additional hint for anyone else who wants a go:

> If you rest on me, I'm an indecision.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are a

> **fence**

If you snatch, I trade.

> A thief uses a fence to trade stolen goods.

If you work with bites, I isolate,

> A dentist uses a [fence](https://www.johnsdental.com/habit/habit-with-lateral-fence/) to discourage a lateral tongue thrust by isolating teeth from the tongue.

If you work with celestial bodies, part of me protects.

> The Space [Fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Fence) is a surveillance system being built to track satellites and debris in Earth orbit.

If you work with the land, I divide.

> A farmer uses a fence to partition land.

Comment: Correct answer. However, what's your reasoning behind "part of me protects"? You actually got a different meaning for "I isolate", but it seems to work just as well! rot13(Pna lbh jbex bhg gur bgure nafjre nffhzvat gung'f gur yvar juvpu hfrf jbeqcynl?) I'm going to add the hint I had lined up if you want a go at that also

Answer (score 1):

Based on the last line,

> Sitting on the fence means that you're indecisive.

If you work with bites...

> Braces look like a fence and they isolate/separate teeth?

The third line:

> The Space Fence’s Early Warning System [protects spaceships from space debris](https://www.airspacemag.com/space/how-things-work-space-fence-180957776/).

Comment: Can you give the reasons which Tom has missed?

Comment: How does this look, @Bee ?

Comment: Did you read my comments on his answer? Third line "**Part** of me protects" is important for the answer I was hoping for. Also, rot13(Ovgrf vf n cynl ba jbeqf) although I liked Toms answer for that and it does work. think rot13(bhgfvqr bs qragvfgel)

Comment: The Early Warning System is part of it, I didn’t think it was the whole thing.